# How do I get a datatable component to update column actions menu?

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

I have a `datatable` column with custom actions defined like this:

```
statusActions = [
    {
        label: 'Show Unconfirmed Leads',
        name: 'unconfirmed_leads',
    }, {
        label: 'Show All My Leads',
        name: 'all_my_leads',
        checked: true,
    }
];
```

The column's menu displays correct with the second item checked. Selecting the first item correctly filters the records (using an `@wired`ed Apex query). But the check doesn't correctly get taken off the second item and placed on the first. Here's the code that is called by the action:

```
handleHeaderAction(event) {
    const name = event.detail.action.name;
    if (name !== this.filter) {
        this.filter = name;
        const actions = this.columns[1].actions;
        for (const action of actions) {
            action.checked = (action.name === name);
        }
        console.log(this.columns[1].actions);
    }
}
```

That last line confirms that the action's are getting updated. Here's the output of the console when the first item is selected:

```
[{label: "Show Unconfirmed Leads", name: "unconfirmed_leads", checked: true}, {label: "Show All My Leads", name: "all_my_leads", checked: false}]
```

The `handleHeaderAction` method is modeled on the example from the [`datatable` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't copy back to the variable, and you don't use @track, changes in an object won't be seen. You need to change the columns definition:

```
@track columns = .......;
```

Or, in your handler:

```
// Shallow copy triggers render cycle
this.columns = [...this.columns];
```

Also, you can change your code to just:

```
const name = event.detail.action.name;
if (name !== this.filter) {
  this.filter = name;
  this.columns[1].actions = this.columns[1].actions.map(action => ({ ...action, checked: action.name === name }));
}
```

Comment: Your second solution did the track. I tried importing `track` and using the decorator as that seems cleaner to me, but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Chuck Yeah, track is kind of limited in depth, but forcing a copy at the top-level is guaranteed to work.